# Install lemonbar from source

Tags: software-installation, compiling, source-packages

I'm having difficulty installing [lemonbar](https://github.com/LemonBoy/bar) package.

Once I've extracted the archive, how do I compile? I'm a bit new so I only know the `./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install` thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need only the below command as there is no `configure` script or anything else:

```
make
```

Keep in mind, `lemonbar` (formerly known as `bar`) is a lightweight bar entirely based on XCB. Therefore you may have to install some other libraries, like `libxcb-xinerama0-dev`. Currently we have two candidates:

```
sudo apt-get install libxcb-xinerama0-dev
sudo apt-get install libxcb-randr0-dev
```

---

Here the full list of steps using `git clone …`

```
cd
git clone https://github.com/LemonBoy/bar.git
cd bar
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I have this error message : cc -Wall -std=c99 -Os -DVERSION="\"a390ef6\"" -o lemonbar.o -c lemonbar.c
lemonbar.c:15:23: fatal error: xcb/randr.h: No such file or directory
 #include <xcb/randr.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [lemonbar.o] Error 1

Comment: I did that already, still not working :(

Comment: Updated my answer